# how to get null values to show?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

So I have to write a query that will display the city, average asking price, and count of the properties with the total for those cities with more than 100 properties. I have the code:

```
SELECT Property.City, '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, AVG(Listing.AskingPrice),1) AS 'Avg. Asking Price', COUNT(Property.PropertyID) AS 'No. of Properties'
FROM Property 
INNER JOIN Listing
ON Property.PropertyID = Listing.PropertyID
GROUP BY Property.City
HAVING COUNT(Property.PropertyID) > 100
```

However, the results should have 3 rows Arcata, Eureka, and NULL. I'm only getting the first two to show up.. How do I make it so my code counts the null values too?

Comment: that gives me four rows and still no null

Comment: Your HAVING clause is what's giving you issues. What exactly are you looking for in your result set? A null value if the count is less than 100? Putting in some sample data and expected outcome would help.

Comment: `ON Property.PropertyID = Listing.PropertyID OR Property.PropertyID IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN ignores matching NULL values. Just Try the below example for verification:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    a int,
    b int
)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
(
    a int,
    b int
)

INSERT INTO @T1 (a,b)
VALUES(1,2)

INSERT INTO @T1 (a,b)
VALUES(NULL,3)

INSERT INTO @T2 (a,b)
VALUES(1,2)

INSERT INTO @T2 (a,b)
VALUES(NULL,3)

SELECT *
FROM @T1 AS T1
INNER JOIN @T2 AS T2 ON T1.a = T2.a
```

If you want to get NULL as result set, use LEFT JOIN instead

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    a int,
    b int
)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
(
    a int,
    b int
)

INSERT INTO @T1 (a,b)
VALUES(1,2)

INSERT INTO @T1 (a,b)
VALUES(NULL,3)

INSERT INTO @T2 (a,b)
VALUES(1,2)

INSERT INTO @T2 (a,b)
VALUES(NULL,3)

SELECT *
FROM @T1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN @T2 AS T2 ON T1.a = T2.a
```